# Как в PHP расшифровать пароль с базы

Tags: php

Как в PHP расшифровать пароль с базы? Сначала я создал хеш пароля и внес его в базу.

```
$hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Как бы его теперь обратно  разхешить и можно ли это?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php - создает хеш пароля используя сильный, необратимый алгоритм хеширования.

Comment: Никак, хеши именно для того и существуют, чтобы «обратно разхешить» было невозможно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php)** создает хеш пароля используя сильный, **необратимый алгоритм хеширования**.

Расшифровать его на лету не получиться. Для любых действий, вам нужно проверить хеш функцией [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 1):

Если необходимо проверить при авторизации, то можно так:

```
$password = $_POST['password'] // например введенный пароль
$hash = '$2y$10$SW2pEdKOuxE3P2Ef7/yvsOFMQUbxS5XjQ2qg2sgYhtu49I4PJ.AX6';
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php